# Synchronous wrapper around Java Websocket Communications?

Tags: java, javascript, swing, tomcat, websocket

I'm currently adapting a desktop swing application for the web.

I'm migrating the front end to an Angular.js app, and leaving the majority of the back end business logic as is (the goal is to be minimally invasive and keep things working for our first iteration). I will interact with the back end service primarily through REST calls. In theory, this should work.

However, I have one little hiccup. The application in its current form relies on numerous prompts to the user before continuing or adjusting the processing of its task. These being done through a desktop swing app, are handled through synchronous alerts (all isolated in a single class, thankfully), the resulting response affecting the application flow.

For example, something like parsing field strings to numbers might be handled through an alert:

```
if (Alert.convertStringsToNumbers()) { // blocking call. Response is boolean value
   // continue processing
} else {
   // abort
}
```

In order to keep the web-app version performant, and without resorting to long-polling, the idea is to swap out the synchronous alerts with websocket communications. However, with sockets being asynchronous, I'm not sure how to pause processing of the task until the user responds to the dialog.

Note, I've spent my last 5 years doing primarily JS work, so I'm assuming there's some extremely simple way I can do this which I'm just not familiar with in Java.

If it helps, I'll be using Tomcat 7 with their catalina implementation of websockets, rather than the standard Java EE 7 version (finally supported in Tomcat 8).

Is it something as simple as wrapping an alert in a runnable, and waiting for a response before returning control to the rest of the application? Or is something more complex required?

**Update** Per the comment below, and to clarify:
The point of the exercise is to push the majority of the app to the server as a service. The front end will be entirely browser based, using Angular.js. To get this version out the door quickly, I want to make the minimally invasive changes to the synchronous api to allow for wrapped, asynchronous communications over websockets.

Comment: Swing and another PLs are single threaded, all updates to the already visible Swing GUI must be done on EDT, `Is it something as simple as wrapping an alert in a runnable,` very close output from thread, Socket, Database, FileIO.... should be wrapped (only methods implemented in Swing APIs, e.g. setText()...., whole methods creates this output) into invokeLater or invoked from SwingWorker, otherwise you can lose every changes from Workers Thread

Comment: So, the point is to no longer use swing at all, but push the majority of the app to the server as a service. The front end will be entirely browser based, using Angular.js. To get this version out the door quickly, I want to make the minimally invasive changes to the synchronous api to allow for wrapped, asynchronous communications over websockets.